# Extracting information from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, match

So I got this string

```
G-Eazy - The track title (Mr. Awesome Remix) (Official Video)
```

Now I would like to extract information like the artist, song title, remix and ignore the information about the official video.

That means that I am just assuming that the first part is the artist's name followed by a space and minus sign and a space again. Then I would like to retrieve the content of the first brackets and ignore all brackets containing words like "official" and so on...

Is there any way to do that using regex?

Comment: It is possible to split on characters and use regex to extract parts of the string. What have you tried?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  But I don't think "is it possible" is really your question.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: I think you would use split(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp . Have you tried something?

Comment: tbh I am struggling with recognizing the minus sign and extract everything before and after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `/^(.+?)\s+\-\s+(.+?)\s*\((.+?)\)/` seems to work as expected.

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/oL2fI8/1)

```js
var string = 'G-Eazy - The track title (Mr. Awesome Remix) (Official Video)';
var matches = string.match(/^(.+?)\s+\-\s+(.+?)\s*\((.+?)\)/);

document.querySelector('pre').textContent =
  'Artist: ' + matches[1] 
+ ' \nTitle: ' + matches[2]
+ '\nRemix: ' + matches[3];
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Output:

> Artist: G-Eazy
>
> Title: The track title
>
> Remix: Mr. Awesome Remix

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of "/(\S+)\s+\-\s+(.+?)\((.+?)\)/" or share a reference to some place where we can learn about it?

Comment: @Shondeslitch The explanation on regex101 might be helpful - https://regex101.com/r/aB0eG3/1

Comment: I don't think this will work if the artist's name has a space in it

Comment: Thank you! +1. Useful answer.

Comment: @Shondeslitch +1 to yours as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling with how to match the `-` that separates the artist from the track name without matching on the `-` in the artist name, then the trick is to match on something like `([^ ]| [^-])+` for the artist name. That will match "anything but a space, or a space not followed by a dash" repeatedly. Obviously we'd like to support spaces in the artist name as well.

For the whole expression, something like this should work:

```
var str = 'G-Eazy - The track title (Mr. Awesome Remix) (Official Video)'
var re = /^((?:[^ ]| [^- ])+) - ([^(]+)(?:\(([^)]+)[Rr]emix\))?/;
var m  = str.match(re); 
console.log('Artist: ' + m[1]);
console.log('Tack  : ' + m[2]);
console.log('Remix : ' + m[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether all the data coming in is in an expected similar format or not, you could do it using the string tokenizing method `.split()`.

```
var string = "G-Eazy - The track title (Mr. Awesome Remix) (Official Video)";

var artist = string.split('-')[0];
alert(artist); // "G-Eazy "
var title = string.split('-')[1].split('(Official')[0];
alert(title); // " The track title (Mr. Awesome Remix) ";

artist = artist.trim();
title = title.trim();

alert(artist + " - " + title); // "G-Eazy - The track title (Mr. Awesome Remix)"
```